# How to get C# 4.0 in Mono (in xbuild)?

Tags: c#-4.0, msbuild, mono

I have a .NET project which uses msbuild that I want to try building in Mono.  I can build some of its trivial targets just fine, but if I try the full compilation it fails.

I'm not sure how much of the output is relevant, but these are the first lines that look like trouble:

```
Target GetFrameworkPaths:
/usr/lib/mono/3.5/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : TargetFrameworkVersion 'v4.0' not supported by this toolset (ToolsVersion: 4.0).
```

and

```
Target ResolveAssemblyReferences:
/usr/lib/mono/3.5/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' not resolved
```

and

```
/usr/lib/mono/3.5/Microsoft.CSharp.targets: error : Error executing tool '/usr/bin/dmcs': ApplicationName='/usr/bin/dmcs', CommandLine='/noconfig @/tmp/tmp4749932e.tmp', CurrentDirectory='/home/ken/foo/bar'
                    Task "Csc" execution -- FAILED
```

I'm running latest Debian unstable.  According to [this](http://mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler), "dmcs" *is* the 4.0 compiler.  I've not used Mono/xbuild much at all -- is there something special it needs in order to compile a C# 4.0 project?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sid still has Mono 2.6, you probably need Mono 2.10 (available in experimental).